# Where can I find all mongodb explain stages name?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB explain is really a good feature to analyze performance. I wonder where I can get all explain stage name. From this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/ it gives me below stages:

```
COLLSCAN for a collection scan
IXSCAN for scanning index keys
FETCH for retrieving documents
SHARD_MERGE for merging results from shards
```

there must be other stages in MongoDB. Where can I get them?

Comment: Why do you think there are more stages